# Cannot save big Word files with Word Web App

Tags: word, office-web-apps

I am using Sharepoint 2013 on premises with Office Web Apps.
I cannot save a doc file through the Office Web Apps browser mode.
The file is almost 50 Mb. 
After about one minute after I have clicked on Save I get an error message that says that the file was not saved and that I should try with Word.
With Word it's saved.

I managed to save it after removing pages until it became about 20 Mb (at 30 Mb didn't work).

The file contains only text and images.

Is there any setting that I should try so that I can save
bigger files in the browser?